# Paypal form how to change text size

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Hi there i got my paypal button which i made on the website. Now its all working fine but the text size is really small for both the drop down box and the text field. Anyway i can change this?

Code which has been generated for me on the paypal website.

```
<div class="paypal">
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="subonly@immaculateclothing.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GB">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Bjj immaculate competition">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="30.00">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Weight Category">Weight Category</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
<option value="-60kg">-60kg </option>
<option value="-65kg (Female Only)">-65kg (Female Only) </option>
<option value="+65kg (Female Only)">+65kg (Female Only) </option>
<option value="-70kg">-70kg </option>
<option value="-80kg">-80kg </option>
<option value="-90kg">-90kg </option>
<option value="-100kg">-100kg </option>
<option value="+100kg">+100kg </option>
</select> </td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Belt Category:">Belt Category:</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os1">
<option value="White">White </option>
<option value="Blue">Blue </option>
<option value="Purple">Purple </option>
<option value="Brown">Brown </option>
<option value="Black">Black </option>
</select> </td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on2" value="Age division">Age division</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os2">
<option value="Adult (16 -35)">Adult (16 -35) </option>
<option value="Master (36+)">Master (36+) </option>
</select> </td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on3" value="Team Name:">Team Name:</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os3" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
</div>
```

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

Use the `font-size` property on your `select` and `input` tags to adjust the size of the text in the fields.

```css
select {
  font-size: 20px;
}

input {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DrydenLong/yHmPe/1/)

Or, if you are just trying to adjust the labels for the fields, use the same `font-size` property as above, but change your selector to `.paypal`

```css
.paypal {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: That is great , thanks so much , but i dont know how to change the size for the actually labels like weight cat, or belt cat or team name etc. Thanks

Comment: @HiThere See the part of my answer after the JSfiddle link.

Comment: Hi there sorry .paypal wont work for the labels , do u have anther way?>

Comment: @HiThere You most likely have some conflicting CSS then. Find what else is styling your `paypal div` and it's children and make the adjustment there.

Comment: ah ok i will try my best but can u explain what is conflicting css?

Comment: @HiThere Conflicting CSS is where you have two rules for the same `selector` and therefore one over-rules the other. This is most likely the reason your labels are not changing when you apply the CSS above. Check out this site to help you with learning some of the basics:
 
http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/

And here for information on how to track down what is doing what to your site: 

http://support.goodlayers.com/how-to-use-google-chrome-inspect-element-tool/